# Pierdo la referencia en mi Clase con varios constructores

Tags: c#

Estoy empezando a hacer mis pruebas en `C#` y me estoy topando siempre con el mismo problema.

Cuando creo una clase y a esta le creo varios constructores, siempre me falla el constructor que no contiene parámetros. Dentro de la clase, este constructor (el que no tiene parámetros) construye el objeto llamando a otro constructor que si que recibe parámetros, el problema es que en cierto punto los valores de los parámetros desaparecen. Cuando ejecuto el programa en modo `debug` veo que el código funciona hasta que llegado a un punto el valor de la variables se pierden.

**Pongo el código:**

```
class Password
  {
    private int Longitud;
    private int Contraseña;

    public Password()
    {
        Password Password = new Password(8);
    }

    public Password(int Longitud)
    {
        this.Contraseña = Generar(Longitud);
    }

    private int Generar(int Longitud)
    {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        if (Longitud == 1)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 9);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 2)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 99);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 3)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 999);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 4)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 9999);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 5)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 99999);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 6)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 999999);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 7)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 9999999);
        }
        else if (Longitud == 8)
        {
            return aleatorio.Next(0, 99999999);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public bool EsFuerte()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(Contraseña).Length > 5;
    }

    public void GenerarPassword(int Longitud)
    {
        this.Contraseña = Generar(Longitud);
    }

    public void MostrarPassword()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Contraseña));
    }

    public int MostrarLongitud()
    {
        Longitud = Convert.ToString(Contraseña).Length;
        return Longitud;
    }

}
    // Este funciona OK
    Password pass1 = new Password(5);

    // Este me decuelve parametros vacios
    Password pass1 = new Password();
```

**Ejemplo**

Si construyo el objeto utilizando el segundo constructor el programa me funciona correctamente y el valor de las variables son los que tienen que ser, en cambio si utilizo el primero, el resultado final no es correcto y el valor de las variables se terminan perdiendo por algún motivo (que tendrá su explicación pero no lo conozco).

Me ocurre cada vez que creo dos constructores y uno llama al otro para `abastecerse` de parámetros que el usuario omite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public Password()
{
    Password Password = new Password(8);
}
```

Esto lo que hace es:

1. Entrar en el constructor sin parámetros para inicializar la instancia.
2. Crear una nueva instancia, **diferente** de `Password` llamando al constructor que acepta un entero.
3. Salir del constructor. La instancia creada con `new Password(8)` deja de estar referenciada, a su debido tiempo el *garbage collector* la eliminará.

Si quieres delegar la inicialización de la instancia que estás inicializando en otro constructor, lo que se hace es:

```
public Password() : this(8) {}
```

Comment: Gracias SJuan76!
Efectivamente es eso lo que me estaba pasando...
Esa sintaxis que has puesto es un poco enrevesada, ¿Es la unica manera de hacero?
Estaba intentando hacer la de java, "this(8)", pero no habia manera...
¿Es la unica manera de llamar al propio constructor?
Lo pregunto para documentarme mejor sobre ello.

Comment: @Edulon así es como lo tiene definido C# que es similar al de Java, la diferencia es que Java reserva la primera línea dentro de las llaves para las llamadas a this o super en este caso C# lo deja después de la declaración del constructor, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente separarlos para que esté más legible en 3 líneas

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de llamar a la segunda definición del constructor

```
public Password() : this(8) {}
```